# SQL Server full-text search using expansion and substitution sets together

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I've looked through the Google monster, but was not able to find much in the way of direction. So, I decided to throw it out there to you guys. Hopefully, I will come across some subject matter experts who can assist.

I'm looking at the FT search features in SQL Server, to use it on my site and need some pointers, help and answers.

Say, for e.g. my thesaurus file looks like this-

```
    <expansion>
        <sub>Garments</sub>
        <sub>Clothing</sub>
        <sub>Dresses</sub>
    </expansion>
    <replacement>
        <pat>Garments</pat>
        <sub>Shirt</sub>
        <sub>Trouser</sub>
        <sub>T-Shirt</sub>
        <sub>Bikinis</sub>
        <sub>Suits</sub>
    </replacement>
    <replacement>
        <pat>Clothing</pat>
        <sub>Shirt</sub>
        <sub>Trouser</sub>
        <sub>T-Shirt</sub>
        <sub>Bikinis</sub>
        <sub>Suits</sub>
    </replacement>
```

1. So, I want us to search for Garments, Clothing and Dresses whenever one of those words is encountered in the user provided search query.
2. I also want to see results for Shirt, Trouser, T-Shirt, Bikinis and Suits when one of the words (Garments, Clothing or Dresses) in my expansion set is searched.

Is this possible by using the above XML? In other words, can the expansion AND replacement sets be used together?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Expansion and replacement sets can be used together, but there should not be duplucates in `/expansion/sub` and `/replacement/pat`.
As far as following expanson set:

```
<expansion>
    <sub>Garments</sub>
    <sub>Clothing</sub>
</expansion>
```

is equal to the following replacement sets:

```
<replacement>
    <pat>Garments</pat>
    <sub>Garments</sub>
    <sub>Clothing</sub>
</replacement>
<replacement>
    <pat>Clothing</pat>
    <sub>Clothing</sub>
    <sub>Garments</sub>
</replacement>
```

you can change your thesaurus file this way:

```
<replacement>
    <pat>Garments</pat>
    <sub>Garments</sub>
    <sub>Clothing</sub>
    <sub>Dresses</sub>
    <sub>Shirt</sub>
    <sub>Trouser</sub>
    <sub>T-Shirt</sub>
    <sub>Bikinis</sub>
    <sub>Suits</sub>
</replacement>
<replacement>
    <pat>Clothing</pat>
    <sub>Clothing</sub>
    <sub>Garments</sub>
    <sub>Dresses</sub>
    <sub>Shirt</sub>
    <sub>Trouser</sub>
    <sub>T-Shirt</sub>
    <sub>Bikinis</sub>
    <sub>Suits</sub>
</replacement>
<replacement>
    <pat>Dresses</pat>
    <sub>Dresses</sub>
    <sub>Garments</sub>
    <sub>Clothing</sub>
    <sub>Shirt</sub>
    <sub>Trouser</sub>
    <sub>T-Shirt</sub>
    <sub>Bikinis</sub>
    <sub>Suits</sub>
</replacement>
```